# My keyboard will not type 'm' or backspace

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am running Arch Linux. Recently, out of nowhere, I have been unable to use the 'm' key or the 'backspace' key on my external keyboard. The keyboard on my laptop works fine.

The keyboard I have plugged in will sometimes work, and other times, it will not type certain keys including, but not limited to, 'm', 'backspace' and the up arrow. I think this may be a locale problem or something, I have my system set to AU because that's where I'm from (Australia).

Comment: Does the external keyboard work on another machine? A locale problem would normally be consistent (not sometimes work, sometimes fail). And would probably affect all keyboards. I'd guess you have a hardware problem w/ that keyboard...

Comment: Do the keys work on a text console? If you run `showkey` on a text console and press these keys, what is the output if any?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused by an incomplete description of your keyboard in `evdev.conf`.

Simplifying, all keyboards your machine is supposed to use must have an entry in a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` (or whatever it's named these days - it varies with the OS, and with the version of X).  Each entry describes, among other things, the layout of the corresponding keyboard.  This layout must, of course, correspond to the physical layout of the keys, otherwise you might press <kbd>m</kbd> and get back a dot, or some similar fun not unlike what you describe.

Now, if you have entries for several keyboards with different layouts, the kernel decides which entry to use when you plug a keyboard in based on things like the path of the corresponding `evdev(4)`, or on USB ID.  These must be set up to *uniquely* identify each keyboard, otherwise you may end up with a keyboard seen by the kernel as another one.  Which might well be the case for you.

Another possible explanation is related to locales, but not directly.  When your sysadmin changed your locales to AU he might have also added keyboard definitions (for your desktop manager, or whatever it's called these days) for a keyboard with an AU layout that you don't have.  If that's the case, there should be some key combination that switches (logical) layouts between US and AU, or whatever.  You need to find that key combination.  How you're supposed to do that depends, of course, on your desktop manager.